# FragmentNavigator add Fragment instead of replace for transparent background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

When using the [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) library from AndroidX, I'd like to display a Fragment with a semi-transparent background on top of the old destination. So basically, instead of the [FragmentNavigator](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/FragmentNavigator) doing `ft.replace(mContainerId, frag)` inside its [navigate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/FragmentNavigator.html#navigate(androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.Destination,%20android.os.Bundle,%20androidx.navigation.NavOptions,%20androidx.navigation.Navigator.Extras)) method, having a `ft.add(mContainerId, frag)` instead.

I've tried subclassing `FragmentNavigator`, but the API is very strongly limited (lots of private variables and package protected methods), thus not being able to properly override the `navigate()` method in order to make that change.

So, what would be the correct method to achieve support for Fragments with transparent background using the Navigation library?

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this problem? @ianhanniballake please can you take a look to this post?

Comment: I already pinged Ian on this one. He said support for DialogFragments is coming soon. Currently I just have another FrameLayout on the same level as the NavController in the root Activity and manually add the Fragment with the transparent background to it, then manually remove it on back pressed. It's not nice, but gets the job done

Comment: Can you guide me how to subclass FragmentNavigator ? I can't seem to understand what to do after extending it.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is **Dialog**, then it is now fully supported as of [2.1.0-alpha03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.1.0-alpha03)

You can achieve your intended behavior with `dialog` destination which will show on top of your current destination.